# How to make headless browser visible Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I have created a headless webdriver chrome browser by setting this argument:

```
 chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

and then opening the browser using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Is it possible to make the browser appear once a condition is met? I have tried removing the attribute again using:

```
chrome_options.arguments.remove("--headless")
```

but that does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

when you pass the --headless parameter to chrome it is actually creating the instance as headless, not creating a window and hiding it, if you wanted to show the instance when a condition is meet you must consider not using --headless at the chrome params.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to remove options/arguments from your Selenium sessions after the session has been started. Each Selenium session is created using a unique session ID and runs with the parameters passed to it until asked to `.quit()`. You will not be able to watch your Chrome session run if you pass it the `--headless` option when you start it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have initiated a `--headless` [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) instance by setting:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

further, it won't be possible to make the *Browsing Context* visible again within the same session.

---

### Reason

When you configure [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) using `ChromeOptions()` to initiate [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) in the process of initiating a new *Chrome Browsing Session* the configuration gets **baked** into the *chromedriver* executable and will persist till the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and remains **uneditable**. So you modify the *ChromeOptions* of the *WebDriver* instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. *Session ID*, *Cookies* and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the current *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721676/how-to-set-selenium-webdriver-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-within-the-same/54722252#54722252)
- [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)
- [How do I make Chrome Headless after I login manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296228/how-do-i-make-chrome-headless-after-i-login-manually/53296911#53296911)