# How do I make Chrome Headless after I login manually

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing my site.
I want the chrome browser to go headless after I manually enter the login credentials.

My selenium code to connect to the website.

```
    var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(); 
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
    //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("exampleDOTcom");

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login and Press Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (CheckLoggedIn())
            break;
    }
    //driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions, 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
```

Comment: Where do you give the options to the driver? What is `driver` defined as?

Comment: You can't, you need to set the headless option before launching the driver.

Comment: @fredrik it can be done, I have seen some applications do it

Comment: I never said it couldn't be done somehow - but your code as is won't compile because there are inconsistencies. You also do not ever give the options to the driver in the code you're showing. Hence no options would be passed to the driver...

Comment: @sham, you can't

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it won't be possible to make Chrome operate **headlessly** after you login manually.

When you configure an instance of a *ChromeDriver* using `ChromeOptions()` or `DesiredCapabilities()` in the process of initiating a new *Chrome Browsing Session* the configuration gets **baked** into the *chromedriver* executable and will persist till the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and being **uneditable**. So you can't add any further *ChromeOptions* to the *WebDriver* instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. **Session ID**, **Cookies**, **UserAgent** and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the current *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721676/how-to-set-selenium-webdriver-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-within-the-same/54722252#54722252)
- [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)

Answer (score 1):

If you need headless browser, Please Specify before the browser opening. i Haven't Seen any applications doing that activity

**Things to pay attention to before using headless browser**:

Headless browsers are simulation programs, they are not your real browsers. Most of these headless browsers have evolved enough to simulate, to a pretty close approximation, like a real browser. Still you would not want to run all your tests in a headless browser. JavaScript is one area where you would want to be really careful before using a Headless browser. JavaScript are implemented differently by different browsers. Although JavaScript is a standard but each browser has its own little differences in the way that they have implemented JavaScript. This is also true in case of headless browsers also. For example HtmlUnit headless browser uses the Rihno JavaScript engine which not being used by any other browser.

Here is Article = https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Check it out!

Comment: headless Chrome *is* a full instance of Chrome.