# How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, google-chrome-headless, firefox-headless

Is it possible after setting selenium webdriver to a headless mode set it back to a normal mode?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(http://stackoverflow.com)

# set driver back to normal mode
```

Comment: its not possible you may need to create new instance or use screenshots

Comment: @PavanKumarTS I want to be able to interact with a webpage if something goes wrong. If I create a new instance I need to load the webpage again.

Comment: options to the Firefox is responsible for running in headless which can be provided only at start there is no other way to modify this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, it won't be possible to make Chrome operate initially in *headless* mode  and then switch back to normal mode within the same session.

When you configure an instance of a *ChromeDriver* with `ChromeOptions()` to span a new *Chrome Browsing Context* the configuration gets *baked* within the *chromedriver* executable which will persist for the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and being **uneditable**. So you can't modify/add any existing/new *configuration* through `ChromeOptions()` class to the *WebDriver* instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. ***Session ID***, ***Cookies***, ***UserAgent*** and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the current *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)
- [How do I make Chrome Headless after I login manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296228/how-do-i-make-chrome-headless-after-i-login-manually/53296911#53296911)

Comment: So, what about Firefox?