# How can I switch from headless mode to normal mode using Google Chrome and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am looking for a solution to open the chrome browser with selenium in headless mode, do some actions and then switch within the same browser in `normal` mode.

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("headless") 
browser =  webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver', options=chrome_options) 
browser.get("https://www.google.de/")

# Do some actions in headless mode
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#L2AGLb > div").click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input").send_keys("Python rocks")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.FPdoLc.lJ9FBc > center > input.gNO89b").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Open Browser
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it won't be possible to open [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) in **headless** mode and moving forward shift to the **headed** mode.

---

### Deep Dive

When you configure an instance of a *ChromeDriver* using `ChromeOptions()`, in the process of initiating a new *Chrome Browsing Session* the configuration gets **baked** into the *chromedriver* executable and will persist till the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and being **uneditable**. So you can't add any further *ChromeOptions* to the *WebDriver* instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. **Session ID**, **Cookies**, **UserAgent** and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the current *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721676/how-to-set-selenium-webdriver-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-within-the-same/54722252#54722252)
- [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar problem as you. We are developing a program that implements Chrome-based automation that performs input tasks after logging in to a specific site.

However, the user must manually log in to the site, and when the user's login is completed, the program must detect the completion of the login and automatically start automatic operation.

And this automated operation must be performed in headless mode.

However, after creating a single Chrome instance in non-headless mode, it was not possible to switch to headless mode. Therefore, I was able to achieve my goal in the following way.

However, to use this method, you must set up a profile path.

The code below uses Selenium in autohotkey.

```
driver := ComObjCreate("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
driver.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" . A_ScriptDir . "\ChromeProfile1")
driver.get("login page url")
;
; user login manually
;
driver2 := ComObjCreate("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
driver2.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" . A_ScriptDir . "\ChromeProfile1")
driver2.AddArgument("--headless")
driver.quit
driver2.get("automatic target page url")
```