# How do I enter a type command onto my selenium script and also turn it into headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium

I am working with the following selenium script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH= r"C:\Users\Hamid\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
cookie_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="L2AGLb"]/div').click()
```

How do I add a command line to enter '*ONS data*' onto the google search tab? Also, how can I turn the window into headless mode?

Comment: Where are you trying to click and which area is the _`google search tab`_?

Comment: So I am writing a code that goes into google.com and then types 'ONS data' into the search bar and clicks search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the character sequence to the *Google Search* area using the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("ONS data")
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

But once you have initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) in headed mode you won't be able to shift to [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless)  mode within the same session.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How can I switch from headless mode to normal mode using Google Chrome and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71623979/7429447)

Comment: I entered the code but unfortunately it gives me the following error:

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("ONS data")
NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined

Thanks. I'll have a read through the link you shared regarding the headless mode.

Comment: @DavidCopperfield Please crosscheck if you have added the desired imports mentioned within the answer?