# In Selenium, how can I disable images or go headless after a certain event?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My script logs into a site and clicks on various buttons.
From the start and until login is complete, there is a chance that a captcha would pop up, which I need to solve manually.

My question is: **after** solviong the captcha, is there a way to tell my script to go headless, or at least disable images? Because of this captcha I'm wasting resources that makes my script slower, because I don't really need to load all the extra stuff in the webpage. I just need it for the captcha.

Edit: my question is a bit different than the one in this thread:
[How can I switch from headless mode to normal mode using Google Chrome and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622167/how-can-i-switch-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-using-google-chrome-and-selen)
Since I'm also asking about disabling images, **or really any suggestion about how can I save resources after the login**, considering I don't need the webpage to visually load in full (I only need to click several buttons).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch from headless mode to normal mode using Google Chrome and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622167/how-can-i-switch-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-using-google-chrome-and-selen)

Comment: you can't really do that since you'll lose your session if you create a new driver.  You might set pageLoadStrategy to "eager", which would not wait for remote resources.  You can use your explicit waits to wait only for the elements you need.

Comment: @pcalkins setting 'pageLoadStrategy' to 'eager' does make the script run faster, thanks