# Selenium: Disable headless when code is running? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, headless, chrome-options

I saw this post:

[How to make headless browser visible Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972282/how-to-make-headless-browser-visible-python)

But apparently it's not possible to disable headless once the code is running, is there an alternative?

My code detects if there is a captcha on the page, displays the window and once the captcha is done it hide again the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, it won't be possible to initialize [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) **headlessly** and then make it visible to solve the [captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309).

When you configure [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) using `ChromeOptions()` to initiate [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) in the process of initiating a new *Chrome Browsing Session* the configuration gets **baked** into the *chromedriver* executable and will persist till the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and remains **uneditable**. So you modify the *ChromeOptions* of the *WebDriver* instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. *Session ID*, *Cookies* and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the current *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721676/how-to-set-selenium-webdriver-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-within-the-same/54722252#54722252)
- [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)
- [How do I make Chrome Headless after I login manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296228/how-do-i-make-chrome-headless-after-i-login-manually/53296911#53296911)